# Accessing parent scope with Object.call

Tags: javascript

I want to access img property in onload function how can i do this ? i added img property to Picture object and calling onload function with scope of Picture object,  still i can not access this.img.

```
// picture
    function Picture(x, y, w, h, imgurl){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.imgurl = imgurl;
        this.draw = drawPic;
        this.overcheck = overRect;
    } // end picture

    function drawPic(){
            this.img = new Image(); // add img to this scope
            this.img.src = this.imgurl;
            this.img.onload = function(){
                //ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.that.x, this.that.y, this.that.w, this.that.h);
                ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h); //error
            } // end onload
            this.img.onload.call(this);
    } // end drawPic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference to `this`

```
function drawPic() {
  var self = this;
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.src = this.imgurl;
  this.img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(self.img, self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h);
  };
}
```

Comment: why can we access self variable directly ? isn't scope in onload function is equal to img object ?

Comment: Nope, `onload` is run from the global scope since it's essentially the `window` object that fires the event. Try doing `console.log(this)` inside of onload and you'll see.

Comment: You're not. You're capturing the variable in [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) meaning you still have access to it inside of another function. It would only be grabbing from the global scope if you did `this.someVariable`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you'll have to define the function inside the object:

```
function Picture(x, y, w, h, imgurl){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
    this.draw = function(){
        this.img = new Image(); // add img to this scope
        this.img.src = this.imgurl;
        this.img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h); //error
        } // end onload
        this.img.onload.call(this);
    } // end drawPic;

    this.overcheck = overRect;
} // end picture
```

Comment: this will create a new function object for every new picture object.

Comment: If you want to take that route, you may as well define it on the prototype: `Picture.prototype.draw = function() { ... }`